# Can't connect to VM remotely

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have Virtual machine with Ubuntu server installed.
Trying to connect to that VM with domain name I have created thru external network.
Up until now I'm able to connect to my VM thru my LAN
**What I did until now**:

- I have open two ports in my router
- I have opened two ports on my guest VM (ubuntu server)
- I have dynamic public IP that I receive via NAT from the ISP
- I'm using no-ip dynamic DNS service to point to my dynamic public IP

**The problem:**

- I can't reach my VM when I try to connect thru the domain name (public IP)
- checking the port on https://www.portchecktool.com/ give message that port is not opened even though I opened the port on the router

What can I do to connect public IP to my VM machine?

Comment: i have reached an understanding that my isp is blocking my ports thru there routers , the question is is there away to bypass that,

Comment: You need to add that info to your question, not as a comment. Basically it turns the thing into a whole new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> checking the port on https://www.portchecktool.com/ give message that port is not opened even though I opened the port on the router

Your port seems to be "not open" as behind the port nothing is going to answer.

*Reason:

In your list is missing the *port forwarding* from the router (public IP) to the VM (local IP). — This has to be configured at your router that is connected to the public IP.*

---

Your connect to your local server:

1. External client tries to connect to VM via `DomainName:Port`
2. DNS-Resolution by NoIP.com changing the request to `Your_public_IP-Address:Port`
3. Your Router gets the request at `Your_public_IP-Address:Port` and forwards it to `Local_IP:Port` (The port number can change here to a different one)
4. The VM gets a request at `Local_IP:Port` and answers it.
5. The router knows the connection, translates `Local_IP:Port` back to the `Public_IP:Port` and sends the answer back to the origin.
6. The client gets the answer.
   It can only see the `Public_ IP:Port` and does not know anything about the internal networking to the VM.

Currently No 3 is missing in your list.

---

#### Update: *ISP prohibits incoming connections*

> according to the ISP the NAT is blocking dynamic public IP addresses. [...]  is there away to bypass NAT server protections? Or they NAT one-to-multiple cannot route

Except of renting a static IP, the only way to bypass this ISP blocking, is to initiate the connection from inside your network.

This depends how sophisticated the block is. One possibility is they block incoming `SYN` packages.
This `SYN` package is the package required to initiate a TCP connection.
An other (probably your case) is the network design. It is similiar to your private network with a NAT one-to-many, so seen from external, the path to your router-IP is not unique and cannot be routed.

For both scenarios the solution is equal:

*Your connection has to start from inside your private network to let the routers learn the path for this connection. Also by this the `SYN` package will come from your local network, the allowed direction.*

By this technique remote service connections, messaging services and video conferencing software circumvent this problem and firewalls. Also Trojan horses and bot slaves do this.

As you probably do not have a static IP on the other end of the network you have to use the No-IP.com service for the other direction, too.

If your client side has the same ISP blocking problem, you need a third server that can be used as "operator" server to establish the connection.

Using a VPN-solution can solve your problem.

- your internet router might have these capabilities.
- A software like OpenVPN is capable
- Also a solution via SSH is thinkable.
- and some more also external services.

But you first should think of how secure your client's network is regarded by you. You should always keep in mind, that *a VPN connection is a direct network connection (often bypassing firewalls) that potentially can be used in both directions!*

So first think about your network design.

Comment: i created tow input rule in router to redirect public ip to local ip , i have created tow rules in iptable to do the same , but still unable to access page

Comment: according to the ISP the NAT is blocking dynamic public IP addresses , and only if I have a static public IP I can forward my ports what should I do about that is there away to bypass NAT server protections

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

in the end it was a problem with the public IP , I couldn't forward my port from a dynamic ip it seems NAT server doesn't allow that, after setting a static public ip problem was solved